# Close dropdown on clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-dropdown-select](https://github.com/sanusart/react-dropdown-select) with the `clearable` option, but when I do clear the dropdown stays open, I'd like it to close once cleared. So far I tried to make a custom Select class and override its `clearRenderer()` callback prop to make use of the `dropDown()` method int it, something like that:

```
class MySelect extends Select {
    clearRenderer = ({ props, state, methods }) => {
        methods.dropDown('close');
    };
}
```

but I can't get it to work.

I'm new to javascript, I'm probably missing something here, thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set closeOnSelect on the dropdown, then it will close when you clear it.

If you want it to stay open on a normal select, then this will work: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-glade-l2hkv. What it's doing is in the onClearAll handler, using a ref to call the method in the select component to toggle the dropdown.

Comment: Yes that does the job, although there's a little glitch (it opens and close the dropdown immediatly). Do you know if there's any way to make the dropdown not to open at all when clearing it ?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do that. They don't give us the event so we can't just stop the propagation. You might actually need to use their clearRenderer to prevent the click from opening the select in the first place.

Comment: I can't get it to not open and close immediately even using the clearRenderer. I might suggest putting up an issue on their github to ask if they can either make the clear button work as you'd expect if there isn't one already. That way if they update the library, things will just work from then on.

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably do that